# Multiple errors when using tikz with caption package

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I am trying to use https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet to create a plot using tikz.
I'm compiling using Overleaf with LuaLaTeX.

I get following errors, only if I use \usepackage{caption}, which i need:

1. Package caption Error: \caption outside float.
2. Argument of @gobbletwo has an extra }.
3. Runaway argument?

My code:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=false, 12pt, a4paper, oneside, parskip=half, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, numbers=noendperiod]{scrbook}

\usepackage{caption}   % without this, there are no errors.

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{import}
\subimport{./layers/}{init}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

% Solved "Class scrbook Error: undefined old font command `\bf'." from scrbook (?)
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\ConvColorR{rgb:red,1;white,5}
\def\ConvColorG{rgb:green,1;white,5}
\def\ConvColorB{rgb:blue,1;white,5}

\foreach \sy/\col in {
    0/\ConvColorR, 
    1/\ConvColorG, 
    2/\ConvColorB
    } {   
    \pic[shift={(\sy * 0.6, 0, 0)}] at (-8, 0,0) {Box={fill=\col,opacity=0.7,height=10,width=1,depth=10}};
}
% Above line is where the errors are located at

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried changing the order between \usepackage{tikz} and \usepackage{caption}

Adding a % after the closing bracket of the foreach block results in different errors:

1. Package caption Error: \caption outside float.
2. Runaway argument?
3. Runaway argument?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without knowing what is inside `init.tex`, it is hard to help you. When commenting out the line with `\subimport` and with `\pic`, the above code compiles fine. So, the error is very likely to be found inside `init.tex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX!

- With the macro `\subimport{./layers/}{init}`, you load the file `init.tex` which can be found here: https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet/tree/master/layers
- The code in this file loads three `sty` files all of which are not compatible with the `caption` package. I explain why in the following.

Let's have a look into the file `Box.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{Box}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This Block can draw simple block of boxes with custom colors. 
% Can be used for conv, deconv etc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{Box/.pic={\tikzset{/boxblock/.cd,#1}
        \tikzstyle{box}=[every edge/.append style={pic actions, densely dashed, opacity=.7},fill opacity=\opacity, pic actions,fill=\fill]
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\cubey*\scale}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\cubez*\scale}
   
        %Multiple concatenated boxes
        \foreach[count=\i,%
                 evaluate=\i as \xlabel using {array({\boxlabels},\i-1)},% 
                 evaluate=\unscaledx as \k using {\unscaledx*\scale+\prev}, remember=\k as \prev (initially 0)] 
                 \unscaledx in \cubex
        {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\unscaledx*\scale}
            \coordinate (a) at (\k-\x , \y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (b) at (\k-\x ,-\y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (c) at (\k    ,-\y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (d) at (\k    , \y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (e) at (\k    , \y/2 ,-\z/2); 
            \coordinate (f) at (\k    ,-\y/2 ,-\z/2); 
            \coordinate (g) at (\k-\x ,-\y/2 ,-\z/2); 
            \coordinate (h) at (\k-\x , \y/2 ,-\z/2); 
        
            \draw [box] 
                (d) -- (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle     
                (d) -- (a) -- (h) -- (e) -- cycle
                %dotted edges
                (f) edge (g)
                (b) edge (g)
                (h) edge (g)    
            ;
            \path (b) edge ["\xlabel"',midway] (c);
            
            \xdef\LastEastx{\k} %\k persists as \LastEastx after loop 
        }%Loop ends
        \draw [box] (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- (c) -- cycle; %East face of last box     
        
        \coordinate (a1) at (0 , \y/2 , \z/2);
        \coordinate (b1) at (0 ,-\y/2 , \z/2);
        \tikzstyle{depthlabel}=[pos=0,text width=14*\z,text centered,sloped]       
        
        \path (c) edge ["\small\zlabel"',depthlabel](f); %depth label
        \path (b1) edge ["\ylabel",midway] (a1);  %height label
        
        
        \tikzstyle{captionlabel}=[text width=15*\LastEastx/\scale,text centered]       
        \path (\LastEastx/2,-\y/2,+\z/2) + (0,-25pt) coordinate (cap) 
        edge ["\textcolor{black}{ \bf \caption}"',captionlabel](cap) ; %Block caption/pic object label
         
        %Define nodes to be used outside on the pic object
        \coordinate (\name-west)   at (0,0,0) ;
        \coordinate (\name-east)   at (\LastEastx, 0,0) ;
        \coordinate (\name-north)  at (\LastEastx/2,\y/2,0);
        \coordinate (\name-south)  at (\LastEastx/2,-\y/2,0);       
        \coordinate (\name-anchor) at (\LastEastx/2, 0,0) ;
        
        \coordinate (\name-near) at (\LastEastx/2,0,\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-far)  at (\LastEastx/2,0,-\z/2);       
        
        \coordinate (\name-nearwest) at (0,0,\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-neareast) at (\LastEastx,0,\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farwest)  at (0,0,-\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-fareast)  at (\LastEastx,0,-\z/2);
        
        \coordinate (\name-northeast) at (\name-north-|\name-east);
        \coordinate (\name-northwest) at (\name-north-|\name-west);
        \coordinate (\name-southeast) at (\name-south-|\name-east);
        \coordinate (\name-southwest) at (\name-south-|\name-west);
        
        \coordinate (\name-nearnortheast)  at (\LastEastx, \y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farnortheast)   at (\LastEastx, \y/2,-\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-nearsoutheast)  at (\LastEastx,-\y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farsoutheast)   at (\LastEastx,-\y/2,-\z/2);
        
        \coordinate (\name-nearnorthwest)  at (0, \y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farnorthwest)   at (0, \y/2,-\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-nearsouthwest)  at (0,-\y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farsouthwest)   at (0,-\y/2,-\z/2);
        
    },
    /boxblock/.search also={/tikz},
    /boxblock/.cd,
    width/.store        in=\cubex,
    height/.store       in=\cubey,
    depth/.store        in=\cubez,
    scale/.store        in=\scale,
    xlabel/.store       in=\boxlabels,
    ylabel/.store       in=\ylabel,
    zlabel/.store       in=\zlabel,
    caption/.store      in=\caption,
    name/.store         in=\name,
    fill/.store         in=\fill,
    opacity/.store      in=\opacity,
    fill={rgb:red,5;green,5;blue,5;white,15},
    opacity=0.4,
    width=2,
    height=13,
    depth=15,
    scale=.2,
    xlabel={{"","","","","","","","","",""}},
    ylabel=,
    zlabel=,
    caption=,
    name=,
}
```

As can be seen, this file defines a macro `\caption` where the value of the option `caption` is stored that can be passed to the `Box` pic. This command, however, is already used by the `caption` package. Therefore, you will get an error here.

A solution would be to use another name (for example `\mycaption`) for the relevant macro in the `sty` files. So, you would need to change two lines (line 53 and line 95) in the `Box.sty` file, so that it becomes the following (Note that the use of `\bf` is discouraged, so I replaced it by `\textbf`):

```
\ProvidesPackage{Box}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This Block can draw simple block of boxes with custom colors. 
% Can be used for conv, deconv etc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{Box/.pic={\tikzset{/boxblock/.cd,#1}
        \tikzstyle{box}=[every edge/.append style={pic actions, densely dashed, opacity=.7},fill opacity=\opacity, pic actions,fill=\fill]
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\cubey*\scale}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\cubez*\scale}
   
        %Multiple concatenated boxes
        \foreach[count=\i,%
                 evaluate=\i as \xlabel using {array({\boxlabels},\i-1)},% 
                 evaluate=\unscaledx as \k using {\unscaledx*\scale+\prev}, remember=\k as \prev (initially 0)] 
                 \unscaledx in \cubex
        {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\unscaledx*\scale}
            \coordinate (a) at (\k-\x , \y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (b) at (\k-\x ,-\y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (c) at (\k    ,-\y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (d) at (\k    , \y/2 , \z/2); 
            \coordinate (e) at (\k    , \y/2 ,-\z/2); 
            \coordinate (f) at (\k    ,-\y/2 ,-\z/2); 
            \coordinate (g) at (\k-\x ,-\y/2 ,-\z/2); 
            \coordinate (h) at (\k-\x , \y/2 ,-\z/2); 
        
            \draw [box] 
                (d) -- (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle     
                (d) -- (a) -- (h) -- (e) -- cycle
                %dotted edges
                (f) edge (g)
                (b) edge (g)
                (h) edge (g)    
            ;
            \path (b) edge ["\xlabel"',midway] (c);
            
            \xdef\LastEastx{\k} %\k persists as \LastEastx after loop 
        }%Loop ends
        \draw [box] (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- (c) -- cycle; %East face of last box     
        
        \coordinate (a1) at (0 , \y/2 , \z/2);
        \coordinate (b1) at (0 ,-\y/2 , \z/2);
        \tikzstyle{depthlabel}=[pos=0,text width=14*\z,text centered,sloped]       
        
        \path (c) edge ["\small\zlabel"',depthlabel](f); %depth label
        \path (b1) edge ["\ylabel",midway] (a1);  %height label
        
        
        \tikzstyle{captionlabel}=[text width=15*\LastEastx/\scale,text centered]       
        \path (\LastEastx/2,-\y/2,+\z/2) + (0,-25pt) coordinate (cap) 
        edge ["\textcolor{black}{\textbf{\mycaption}}"',captionlabel](cap) ; %Block caption/pic object label
         
        %Define nodes to be used outside on the pic object
        \coordinate (\name-west)   at (0,0,0) ;
        \coordinate (\name-east)   at (\LastEastx, 0,0) ;
        \coordinate (\name-north)  at (\LastEastx/2,\y/2,0);
        \coordinate (\name-south)  at (\LastEastx/2,-\y/2,0);       
        \coordinate (\name-anchor) at (\LastEastx/2, 0,0) ;
        
        \coordinate (\name-near) at (\LastEastx/2,0,\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-far)  at (\LastEastx/2,0,-\z/2);       
        
        \coordinate (\name-nearwest) at (0,0,\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-neareast) at (\LastEastx,0,\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farwest)  at (0,0,-\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-fareast)  at (\LastEastx,0,-\z/2);
        
        \coordinate (\name-northeast) at (\name-north-|\name-east);
        \coordinate (\name-northwest) at (\name-north-|\name-west);
        \coordinate (\name-southeast) at (\name-south-|\name-east);
        \coordinate (\name-southwest) at (\name-south-|\name-west);
        
        \coordinate (\name-nearnortheast)  at (\LastEastx, \y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farnortheast)   at (\LastEastx, \y/2,-\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-nearsoutheast)  at (\LastEastx,-\y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farsoutheast)   at (\LastEastx,-\y/2,-\z/2);
        
        \coordinate (\name-nearnorthwest)  at (0, \y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farnorthwest)   at (0, \y/2,-\z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-nearsouthwest)  at (0,-\y/2, \z/2);
        \coordinate (\name-farsouthwest)   at (0,-\y/2,-\z/2);
        
    },
    /boxblock/.search also={/tikz},
    /boxblock/.cd,
    width/.store        in=\cubex,
    height/.store       in=\cubey,
    depth/.store        in=\cubez,
    scale/.store        in=\scale,
    xlabel/.store       in=\boxlabels,
    ylabel/.store       in=\ylabel,
    zlabel/.store       in=\zlabel,
    caption/.store      in=\mycaption,
    name/.store         in=\name,
    fill/.store         in=\fill,
    opacity/.store      in=\opacity,
    fill={rgb:red,5;green,5;blue,5;white,15},
    opacity=0.4,
    width=2,
    height=13,
    depth=15,
    scale=.2,
    xlabel={{"","","","","","","","","",""}},
    ylabel=,
    zlabel=,
    caption=,
    name=,
}
```

You need to do the same with the two other `sty` files that are loaded by `init.tex` which are `Ball.sty` (changes to be made in lines 21 and 28) and `RightBandedBox.sty` (changes to be made in lines 70 and 111).

Output (without errors):

[image]

Comment: That's the solution! Thanks a lot!!